# What does this code from go sources mean? Like (*(*float32)(v.ptr))

Tags: go, type-conversion

In reflection package I see the code like

```golang
    return float64(*(*float32)(v.ptr))
```

What is *(*float32)(v.ptr)? I don't have any ideas

Comment: @JimB that's similar but much, much simpler than the code quoted in the question, which involves a combination of conversion, assertion, and dereferencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's unwrap the expression. We'll take it from innermost to outermost, since that's the order it's evaluated:

```
(*float32)(v.ptr)
```

Convert `v.ptr` to `*float32`, a pointer to a `float32`.

```
*(*float32)(v.ptr)
```

Dereference that pointer, giving us a `float32` value.

```
float64(*(*float32)(v.ptr))
```

Convert the `float32` value to a `float64` value.

So, whatever `v.ptr` is, it's converted to a `float32` pointer, dereferenced, and then converted to `float64`, and returned.

Comment: FTR, `v.ptr` is an `unsafe.Pointer`, which is how it can be converted into any pointer type.

Comment: That was my guess but there wasn't enough context given to be sure of its type.

Comment: Thank you! That pointer in type conversion made me a little bit confused

Comment: It looks a little unusual because of that; the reason is that just `*float32(v.ptr)` would try to convert to a `float32` value and then dereference it (which you can't do because it's not a pointer), so the type has to be wrapped in parens.

Comment: If ```unsafe.Pointer``` can be converted into any pointer type why cant we just do smth like ```*(*float64)(v.ptr)```

Comment: Because that's not the actual underlying type. That would take the next 64 bits of memory starting at the pointer location and treat it as a `float64`, when the actual value is only 32 bits long.

Comment: @Adrian Now I understand this. Thank you very much again!